# "Coul not find a suitable Class::Load implementation"

Tags: perl-module

I am bulding an executable with PAR but It gives me the next error:

"Could not find a suitable Class::Load implementation :  at Class/Load.pm line 51.

I  would  like to kwon why It makes that error.

Anyone could givbe me a solution please?

Answer (score 2):

For some reason PAR can't find `Class::Load::XS` or `Class::Load:PP`.

You can try if those are at all on your include path with eg.: `perl -MClass::Load::PP -e1`

If not, try to (re?)install them or fix your classpath. The corresponding files in your filesystem should be `Class/Load/XS.pm` and `Class/Load/PP.pm`.

If the oneliner doesn't give you an error, it could be that PAR uses different include paths.

You can debug your include paths with eg. `perl -le 'print for @INC'` and temporarily add something to the path with the `-I/my/path` switch. Or you can `use lib '/my/path';` in you perl files.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it running pp with both -x and -c parameters

```
pp -x -c script.pl
```